# Запись чисел из файла в массив типа int

Tags: c++

Встал перед вопросом, как считать числа из текстового файла напрямую в массив.

```
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    if (!in)
    {
        cout << "File not found" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
    //сколько чисел в файле
    int count = 0;
    int temp;

    while (!in.eof())
    {
        in >> temp;
        count++;// счетчик числа чисел
    }


    in.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    in.clear();


    int count_space = 0;
    char symbol;
    while (!in.eof())
    {

        in.get(symbol);
        if (symbol == ' ') count_space++;
        if (symbol == '\n') break;
    }
```

Наваял пока только это, дальше ухожу в гору ошибок. Подскажите решение, если можно как-то проще решить эту задачу был бы рад узнать как.
Числа могут быть представлены по разному: в одной строке, в нескольких строках, с кучей пробелов между ними(не знаю, как адаптировать свои условия к этому).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Где же у вас правильный вопрос?... В заголовке - числа из файла в массив. Я отвечаю на него.

Вам нужен именно массив в C'шном смысле? Или в C++'ном, где его с успехом заменяет вектор? :)

Проще всего, пожалуй, так:

```
vector<int> data;
...
int n;
while(in >> n) data.push_back(n);
```

А в тексте - уже говорите о символах. Вы уж определитесь...

И еще - проверять `while(!in.eof())` - неверно, потому что флаг конца файла будет выставлен **после неудачного чтения за концом файла**, т.е. вы можете стоять на конце файла, но `in.eof()` вернет `false`.

**Update**

```
int n, count = 0;
while(in >> n) ++count;

in.clear();
in.seekg(0, ios::beg);

int * data = new int[count];
count = 0;
while(in >> n) data[count++] = n;
```

Comment: спасибо за правку, действительно только числа. Вектор использовать нельзя, массив в С++'ном смысле) Нужно выгрузить именно в обычный int'овский массив.

Comment: просто сам сделал все с вектором, а его оказывается использовать нельзя, такие требования.

Comment: Ну тогда примерно как в обновленном ответе...

Comment: А почему нужны эти 2 строчки вначале: in.clear();
in.seekg(0, ios::beg);   ???

Comment: Потому что `while(in >> n) ++count;` загонит позицию чтения из файла в его конец, и выставит признак конца файла. Вот для того, чтоб привести файл в нормальное состояние, и нужны эти строчки...